# How to sort std::array with std::sort?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    array<char, 20> test{"HelloWorld"}, tmp;

    // method 1
    tmp = test;
    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.begin() + strlen(tmp.begin()));
    cout << "result: " << tmp.data() << endl;

    // method 2
    tmp = test;
    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    cout << "result: " << tmp.data() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`std::array` can be sorted with method 1. But it's so ugly.

I prefer method 2, but nothing can be returned. What's wrong with it?

Comment: The two `sort` calls do different things. Use the one that does what you need.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you're trying to get an `std::array` to be an `std::string`. It's not, and trying to use it as one is never going to work very well.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string`? Then method 2 would Just Work.

Comment: `end()` points outside range of an array, and `begin()+strlen(...)` points at the end of actual string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second method is sorting all the `\0` elements to the front.  (They *are* less than any of the other characters.

When you try and print it with `.data()` you get a `char const*` object back which to the stream class is treated like a C-String. Which is a null terminated string. Since the first character is a null it prints nothing.

You could fix with

```
    auto cmp = [](char a, char b) { return a != '\0' && a<b; }
    sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), cmp);
```

This uses a comparator which sorts `\0` at the end.

But as Jerry Coffin said in comments, `std::array` is not `std::string` - use the one which fits your needs (probably `std::string` in this case).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Thanks for the addition - that's much better.

Answer (score 2):

You're printing a C-String, which relies on the existence of a terminating null character: `\0`.
When you sort the entire array, you move that null character to the front, which tells your print functions that it is an empty string.

Thus, you have no choice but to use the uglier version.  That being said, here's a safer way to write it which you may prefer:

```
sort(tmp.begin(), find(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), '\0'));
```

Comment: Not sure how that's cleaner.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley `tmp.begin() + strlen(tmp.begin())` does extra work.

Comment: What work is that? If I had to guess which one does more work, it would be your version, since it needs to compare the value of the iterator itself (to the end iterator), as well as the dereferenced value (to 0). Whereas `strlen` is only checking the dereferenced value.

Comment: @Ben I suppose so, I didn't think to consider that.  I'd still prefer this version, so I'll just edit my wording.

Comment: One advantage yours does have though is that it's safer.